# Group by and return row with highest value each group

Tags: sql, oracle

This is `table1`:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | a |
| 1 | 5 | b |
| 1 | 4 | NULL |
| 4 | 1 | C |
| 4 | 3 | D |

What I want as a result should look like this:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | b |
| 4 | 3 | D |

I want to group by ID and take the row with highest `Value1` inside the group.

I'm working with Oracle SQL, I'm trying with group by but no luck.

Comment: check this answer. ROW_NUMBER will help you to achieve this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group?rq=2